# MySQL SELECT fist X rows without an index

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I am looking for a way to execute a SELECT query on a large table without having to add any new indexes.

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE column_1 = "" limit 100
```

there is bout 800,000 of these empty rows and about 5 million of filled ones.

In my mind there has to be a way where the database engine just starts reading the table from one end, collects the first 100 rows (regardless of the order) and stops. However with the above query it checks all the 5M rows.

I did search the internet with no answer. Could someone help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: I read through, and what I do not understand is that, while I am using the LIMIT clause it still scans the entire table. Why? It shouldn't.

Comment: 'scans the entire table.Why? It shouldn't' -  the optimizer thinks differently and not much you can do about that. Limit btw is not a read limit from the db  it's a limit on the rows returned from the result set.

Comment: possibly the reason: *If you select only a few rows with LIMIT, MySQL uses indexes in some cases when normally it would prefer to do a full table scan.*? So if there is no index MySQL checks the full table? With index MySQL checks only the 800,000 rows.

Comment: Why don't you add an index? I think there would be no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"it checks all the 5M rows" -- If you are using `EXPLAIN` to say that, don't trust it.  `EXPLAIN` rarely adjusts its "Rows" column to account for `LIMIT`.

OTOH, If only the last 100 rows were blank, it *would* read all 5M rows.  If the first 100 rows are blank, the only 100 would be read.  The Optimizer is not smart enough to know which of those will happen.

With `INDEX(column1)`, it will touch only 100 *index* rows and get the ids (which are in the index's BTree.  If you want more than just `id`, there is an extra step (performed 100 times) to reach into the data's BTree to get the rest of the columns.

If you want to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to see the engine, `PRIMARY KEY`, datatypes, etc.

Are you first fetching 100 ids, then fetching something based on them?  That is almost always less efficient than combining the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

One way or the other, I would add an index to "column_1".

I am pretty sure MySQL does not give you any possibility to influences this.

What you can try is doing a Stored procedure, which does a select 
"SELECT id FROM table_name" then filters on "column_1 = """ and stops after counting 100 positives.

If there are any better methods, I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: A Stored Proc will have more overhead; don't consider such.